# How to wrap text on column#2

Tags: shell, vim

I have a text file:

```
Function        Description

concat          Returns the concatenation of the arguments.

contains        Returns true if the first argument string contains the second argument string; otherwise returns false.
```

I'd like to wrap the text on column#2, the result should be:

```
Function        Description

concat          Returns the concatenation
                of the arguments.

contains        Returns true if the first
                argument string contains 
                the second argument
                string; otherwise returns
                false.
```

How to do it in `vim` or `shell` quickly? Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue can be easily solved in Vim by using the `indentexpr` option.  Set
it to the number of characters designated for the first column,

```
:set inde=16
```

then format the text as usual with the `gq` or `gw` families of commands.

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way than mine!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this qualifies as "quickly", and I hope someone out there has a better answer, but this is the best I could come up with in vim:

1) Set textwidth to the desired width of your second column:

```
:set tw=60
```

2) Mark the first-column words with something special (to be removed later - any non-normal text will do, I'm using jjj here) (using `g!/^$/` to ignore empty lines):

```
:%g!/^$/s/^/jjj/
```

3) Put the second column text on a separate line:

```
:%s/ \</ \r/
```

4) Rewrap all the second-column lines to the desired width:

```
:%g!/^jjj/normal gqq
```

5) Join the first line of each second-column paragraph with its first-column word (should preserve the space that was after the first-column words at the beginning):

```
:%g/^jjj/join
```

6) Indent all the remaining second-column lines the appropriate amount to line them up (use however many `>>`s are needed - there may be a way to make vim check the length of the last first-column line and insert that number of spaces instead of using this method):

```
:%g!/^jjj/normal >>>>>>>>
```

7) Finally remove the first-column marker from the first columns:

```
:%s/^jjj//
```

Not worth it for your example, but if the file's large enough, it's better than doing it by hand...

Answer (score 0):

```
:set tw=80 #or :set textwidth=80
```

Would wrap text to 80 chars.

Then you can type in command mode:

```
gg #go to the top
```

and then

```
gqG #apply reformat to the end
```

Reference:
http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/vim/reformatting.html

Comment: I don't think 'gq' in this case will achieve OP's goal.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that leaves the second-column lines unindented, unlike the example, so they don't line up in the second column...